# CALayer and view disappeared

Tags: objective-c, ios, drawing, catiledlayer

I have a large image managed with CATiledLayer (like the [Large Image Downsizing iOS sample code](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/LargeImageDownsizing/Introduction/Intro.html)).

I had a drawing view (UIView overrided with drawing methods) on it but when I zoom a lot, I get the following message and my view disappeared..

```
-[<CALayer: 0xb253aa0> display]: Ignoring bogus layer size (25504.578125, 15940.361328)
```

Is there a way to avoid this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like the levelsOfDetail and levelsOfDetailBias you are setting are allowing for more zoom than the tiled layer should allow given the max layer size allowable for the layer.  Try changing those to lessen how much the user can zoom.

[Here](http://red-glasses.com/index.php/tutorials/catiledlayer-how-to-use-it-how-it-works-what-it-does/) is a great article explaining some of the undocumented behavior of CATiledLayer.

Comment: Indeed, you're right, when I change the levelsOfDetail and levelsOfDetailBias, I can zoom more before the view disapeared. Thanks a lot.

Comment: A last question : is there an effect on the performance if I set the levelsOfDetail and levelsOfDetailBias at a big level ?

Comment: added an article link to the answer that has a lot of information regarding memory management of tiles and some undocumented behavior, hope this helps.